# PHPMailer Html error

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

im trying to send an Html email with PHPMailer.

But everytime i get this error: Fatal error parsing.......

I cant put in my php or html code here because then it wont let me post my message here. But the problem has to something with the double qoutes like ". There are all over my html code. When i modify my html code and delete all the " double quotes the mail will be send, but of course with pretty much no content. So, the double quotes are needed in my html code. How do i modify my php so it wont give me an error as soon as it sees an double quote?
Thanks guys.

Comment: Fatal error parsing what? And what do you mean "it wont let me post my message here"?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u427019371/public_html/phpmail.php on line 23

Comment: cant post my code because it always says there is some code wrong formated or anything. My body section on my php looks like that: $mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = "<html><body><div><div style="font-family: 
</body>
</html>";

Comment: Post the code, please

Comment: Use single quotes instead or escape quotes before hand

Comment: tried posting the code, no freaking idea how to do it, the help sections here didnt helped me in any way

Comment: i tried replacing every double quote with a single quote, the html mail send was completely empty then

Comment: hello? so i guess there is no solution for that?

Comment: What is the code on line 23 of phpmail.php?

Comment: the code in line 23 is </html>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mail->Body = "<html><body><div><div style="font-family: </body> </html>"
```

You are using double quotes to wrap the html, but you are breaking out of them again on the style `style="font-family:`

Use single quotes to wrap the whole html or for the style declaration

Comment: well that didnt work, because in my whole html code i have both single quotes and double quotes, something like that: <html><body><div><div style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;"><img       so what do i use then to wrap up the html?

Comment: You will need to escape the double quotes within the html using a backslash. `\"`

Comment: oh gosh, im a complete noob, i dont even know what that means. you mean putting a \ before every "? my html code is massive, that would take me ages to do that by hand.

Comment: Then escape the single quotes in the html and wrap it all in single quotes rather than double. Either way you are going to have to escape one of the types of quotes. Or you could add your html into another file and use `$mail->Body = file_get_contents('file.html')` to set the body

Comment: yeah i heard abou that $mail->Body = file_get_contents('file.html'), does it mean there i can just put in my html code like it comes out of my "html creation software" or do i also need some modification on the code there?#

Comment: you can just have file.html contain only the html as long as you arent referencing any variables in it.

Comment: ok that kinda worked, only problem......letters like Ä or Ü or Ö wont get displayed correct, they are just a random mess

Comment: You will need to provide a character set in your html file. Something like `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: nah, dont think it will ever work. Even if i get something to work there is a new problem. If i put youre code in my html file it will also show that code in my send mail after that. How should i put that in my html file put i shouldnt show in the mail afterwards?

Comment: add the meta tag I specified to the <head> of your html `<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />`. It wont be rendered as its just an element. It will be visible in the source code but wont be visible on the page.

Comment: didnt work, still just random letters in the final mail

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to start a new question with this problem rather than let this conversation get too big. You could also mark my answer as accepted ;) Even though you still have issues I helped with the original error.